# how to add,edit,delete with pouch db and angularJS or where can i find relevant tutorials?

Tags: angularjs, pouchdb

i've created a service and a controller but the tutorial im following its not really clear how to go about creating add/edit and delete functions how do i go about doing that. or where can i find angular pouch that explains that.

```js
.service('pouchdb', [
  function() {
    return new PouchDB('myApp');
  }
]);
```

```js
.controller('pouchDB', function($scope,pouchdb) {
var dbLocal = new PouchDB('LimaT');
var dbRemote = new PouchDB('http://localhost:5984/LimaT');

  //add

 //edit

//delete



})
```

Answer (score -1):

// add

```
var doc = {
  "_id": "mittens",
  "name": "Mittens",
  "occupation": "kitten",
  "age": 3,
  "hobbies": [
    "playing with balls of yarn",
    "chasing laser pointers",
    "lookin' hella cute"
  ]
};
db.put(doc);
```

// edit

```
// fetch mittens
db.get('mittens').then(function (doc) {
  // update their age
  doc.age = 4;
  // put them back
  return db.put(doc);
}).then(function () {
  // fetch mittens again
  return db.get('mittens');
}).then(function (doc) {
  console.log(doc);
});
```

taken from https://pouchdb.com/guides/documents.html

// delete

```
db.get('mittens').then(function (doc) {
  return db.remove(doc);
});
```

taken from https://pouchdb.com/guides/updating-deleting.html

Comment: not sure why this has been voted down, can you explain what else you are looking for?